# Evaluate function

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

Is there a better way to write the following?

```
<cfloop list="#qry.Columnlist#" index="FieldName">
   <cfset "form.#FieldName#" = Evaluate("qry.#FieldName#")>
</cfloop>
```

This loop is assigning every field in the query to a corresponding form field.
I understand the evaluate function is shunned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<cfloop list="#qry.Columnlist#" index="FieldName">
    <cfset form[FieldName] = qry[FieldName][1]>
</cfloop>
```

?

Comment: Good answer! I was looking for a solution to this today too.

Comment: What about `evaluate("qry.#myArr[i].foo#")` I tried `qry[myArr[i][foo]]` but no luck

Comment: @isurfbecause not sure what u're asking there, but for array object, it's `[fieldName][rowIndex]`.  Is `foo` the rowIndex?  if so, set `myArr[1]` to some var first, then use that.  CF might not like nested `[]`

Comment: myArr is an array of structs, so foo is an attribute in the struct.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are returning a single recordset the following will work.

```
<cfloop list="#qry.Columnlist#" index="FieldName">
<cfset "form.#FieldName#" = qry[FieldName][1]>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Technically, there is nothing wrong with that. But you may as well go the whole way and use array notation for both sides of the cfset ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tangential, but if you were looping over multiple rows of a query, you could use the `currentRow` variable in the query object to do the same thing as the accepted answer.

```
<cfset var someStruct = {} />
<cfset var colummnList = queryObj.columnList />

<cfloop query="queryObj">
    <cfset someStruct[currentRow] = {} />        

    <cfloop list="#columnList#" index="fieldName">
        <cfset someStruct[currentRow][fieldName] = queryObj[fieldName][currentRow] />
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Very interesting. I'm getting confused mixing struct notation and array notation, but I'll look into this.  Thanks!

Comment: Yah sorry, {} is shorthand for StructNew() and [] is shorthand for ArrayNew(1)